# Dropzone working properly on localhost, throws error on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I have already configured dropzone and tested it on my localhost(which is a Windows machine). Everything is working properly, the files are being uploaded and processed appropriately by Laravel. The problem is that the same thing is not happening on my web server. The code is the same on both machines. On windows, dropzone in a div is displayed properly(with the text saying to drag and drop the files), but on the web server the text is not displayed and I can't click on the zone.

> Chrome dev tools say: `Uncaught error: No URL provided`

even though I have the urls configured. I googled this error and found that disabling autoDiscover should resolve it. I tried this but then it didn't work even on the local server.

This is my dropzone options file:

```
Dropzone.options.editFilijalaDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

  // The configuration we've talked about above
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  maxFiles: 10,
  addRemoveLinks: false,
  acceptedFiles: '.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif',
  url: "/uploadNew/filijale/filijala/" + document.getElementById('filijala_hidden').value,
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
  // The setting up of the dropzone
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
    var element = document.getElementById('edit_filijala_submit');
    var form = document.getElementById('edit_filijala_form');
    element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
      // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
      // Hide the success button or the complete form.
    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
      // Redirect user or notify of success.
            form.submit();
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
      // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error

    });
  }
}
```

The HTML in question is:

```
<h1>Ažuriranje filijale za firmu: {{ $firma->naziv }}</h1>

    <!-- if there are creation errors, they will show here -->
    {{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

        {!! Form::model($filijala, [
            'method' => 'PUT',
            'action' => array('FilijalaAdminController@update', $firma->id, $filijala->id),
            'id' => 'edit_filijala_form'
    ]) !!}


    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Naziv firme', 'Naziv firme') !!}
        {!! Form::text('naziv_firme', $firma->naziv, array('class' => 'form-control', 'readonly')) !!}
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::hidden('filijala_hidden', $filijala->id, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'filijala_hidden')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Adresa filijale', 'Adresa filijale') !!}
        {!! Form::text('adresa', Input::old('adresa'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Telefon', 'Telefon') !!}
        {!! Form::text('telefon', Input::old('telefon'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Email', 'Email') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Uklanjanje slika', 'Uklanjanje slika') !!}
            <div class="row">
                @foreach($slike as $slika)
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">

                            <a <?php echo 'href="#imageOverlay' . $slika->id . '"'; ?> data-toggle="drop-panel" class="thumbnail">
                                <img <?php echo 'id="image' . $slika->id . '"'; ?> class="img-responsive" src="{{ $slika->url }}">
                            </a>
                            <div <?php echo 'id="imageOverlay' . $slika->id . '"'; ?> class="cap-overlay show">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <a href="javascript:obrisiSliku('{{ $slika->id }}', 'filijale')" class="button small"><h5>Obriši sliku</h5></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                {!! $slike->render() !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Dodavanje slika', 'Dodavanje slika') !!}
            <div class="dropzone" id="edit_filijala_dropzone">
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Ažuriraj filijalu', array('id' => 'edit_filijala_submit')) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The server is a CentOS linux machine.

EDIT:

The generated HTML:

```
<html><head>
    <title>Ažuriranje filijale</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="9dglsQuYuxZEcbko7sCwj8PMzQgbwFlpnfwlT5Gr">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dropzone.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/thumbnail-gallery.css">
  <style>
    .cap-overlay .button { margin-top:10px}
    .cap-overlay{width: 100%; color:#fff; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);left:0;padding:12px; line-height: 1.4em;font-size:14px}
    .cap-overlay h5 {color:#fff;}
    a[data-toggle="drop-panel"] {display: block;}
  </style>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="http://5.189.145.111/admin_firme/2">Sve filijale za firmu</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://5.189.145.111/admin_firme/2/filijale/create">Nova filijala</a>
            </li></ul>
</nav>




<h1>Ažuriranje filijale za firmu: Kaymo PROPO LIST d.o.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              </h1>

    <!-- if there are creation errors, they will show here -->
    

        <form method="POST" action="http://5.189.145.111/admin_firme/2/filijale/8" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="edit_filijala_form"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="9dglsQuYuxZEcbko7sCwj8PMzQgbwFlpnfwlT5Gr">


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Naziv firme">Naziv firme</label>
        <input class="form-control" readonly="readonly" name="naziv_firme" type="text" value="Company X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ">
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="filijala_hidden" name="filijala_hidden" type="hidden" value="8">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Adresa filijale">Adresa filijale</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="adresa" type="text" value="dsasad                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Telefon">Telefon</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="telefon" type="text" value="033 256 987                                                                                         ">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" value="                                                                                 ">
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Uklanjanje slika">Uklanjanje slika</label>
            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">

                            <div class="drop-panel" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: block; padding: 2px;"><a href="#imageOverlay22" data-toggle="drop-panel" class="thumbnail">
                                <img id="image22" class="img-responsive" src="\image\filijale\192971848455d4d775787cb4.79487595.jpg">
                            </a><div id="imageOverlay22" class="cap-overlay show" style="display: block; width: 345px; height: 321px; position: absolute; z-index: 3; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: -321px;">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <a href="javascript:obrisiSliku('22', 'filijale')" class="button small"><h5>Obriši sliku</h5></a>
                                </div>
                            </div></div>
                            
                    </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Dodavanje slika">Dodavanje slika</label>
            <div class="dropzone" id="edit_filijala_dropzone">
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="edit_filijala_submit" type="submit" value="Ažuriraj filijalu">
    </div>

    </form>




</div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery.hcaptions.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/slike_akcije.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dropzone.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dropzone_options.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function () {
      $('[data-toggle=drop-panel]').hcaptions();
    });
  </script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: knowing the error would be helpful..

Comment: @iam-decoder Chrome dev tools say: 'Uncaught error: No URL provided', as is written in the question.

Comment: Can you post the generated html...

Comment: @Hackerman Edit posted.

Comment: I build a fiddle with your info...it shows no error: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/zL8LbqLb/

Comment: @Hackerman I don't know. On the server it only works if I set the whole form to class dropzone.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line before setting your options

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

Comment: It may also be useful to set autoDiscover to false outside of the jQuery onReady("document"). If you wait for the document to be ready dropzone will have already tried to find dropzone elements in the page.